# HTML Table footer in @media print with different content on each page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a table that represents a bill/invoice. It can span multiple pages, so on the last page I want to display total costs in the footer, but in the previous footers, I want to display the subtotal ones.

Is something like that possible to achieve without creating multiple tables? Creating multiple ones would have the downside of having to either calculate the table height dynamically or limit it to some pragmatic number of items per page so the table chunks never overflow from the page

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem properly I think. Could you show us a snippet of code - especially the bit where you calculate the subtotals to put on the other pages.

Comment: @AHaworth there is no JS/CSS/HTML code. Right now we are using a hard to maintain solution where we create multiple tables by calculating if they fit on one A4 page. I want to know if this whole process can be avoided.

Comment: I not using JS, what are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth With Java code, creating multiple tables from mustache templates, one table per page. As you can imagine, it is a pain in the ass to calculate what fits in a page based on existing headers, footers and additional content. I want to do that directly in mustache with HTML/CSS/JS instead, if it is possible.